# Custom lock screen image - Terminal Server 2012 over RDP

Tags: windows, terminal, remote-desktop, screensaver, lock-screen

Wanting to set a custom lock screen background image for when session is locked due to idle time. Running a terminal services farm setup so users will be connecting over RDP. Anyone able to advise if this can be adjusted?

I have tried a few things suggested;

- Setting the OEMbackground key in registry and placing the .jpg in \system32\oobe\info\backgrounds
- configuring GPO to force a lock screen background (did not work, tried with both .png and .jpg).
- Compiling a screensaver file .scr and forcing this to start when session is locked (did not work, tried with both group policy and via batch file execution with task scheduler)

Anyone able to advise on how this could be adjusted? If there is a file that can replaced that would be great. I have checked in \windows\web but none of those images seem to be relevant to the default lock screen im seeing. I know the screensaver method should not work by design because of RDP 'disconnected' sessions and then the screensaver taking up un-needed server resource which makes sense, but for just general idle time locks surely we can change this?

Thanks